# Image Recognition to drive test automation

Tags: wpf, image, testing, automation, image-recognition

Are there any tools out there which uses Image Recognition(searching, comparing, validating images) as base for automating and testing GUI software.I know ranorex supports it. Are there any better tools?Are there any gotchas in using Image Recognition to drive test automation?

Comment: Obvious gotcha - discrepancies between agent machine settings. If you build a test on 1280 resolution, but play it back at 1150, you are going to run into problems. Typically, you are better off driving your automation at the GUI object level or at the API level. My experience is that using image recognition for driving test automation should be used only as a last resort.

Comment: I agree with RodKnee and Tom E. Using image recognition for UI testing is nothing short of extremely painful and a waste of time. If your application is correctly built you can push the UI logic into a different layer of your application that is more easily tested. The [MVP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) was created for this very purpose. Each operation that can be accomplished via the UI is represented somewhere in the View. In this way, you can strip out the UI completely and still unit test your application using the remaining architecture (M-V-C). The thought o

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first of all, I DO understand the previous answers: testing apps using image recognition isn't the best way to test GUIs. But, at the same time, I don't understand why you aren't answering the question in first place. He's asking for tools that work that way, I'd think he's smart enough to understand where he's going into.

Ok, now the main subject, my choice would includes:

- [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org), a MIT project under the GNU-like MIT license. It uses Python over Jython. Free.
- [TestPlant eggPlant](http://www.testplant.com/products/eggplant/), a tool that works through a VNC server, so you can test apps in any VNC compatible platform (including smartphones). It has some nice features like OCR, test schedule and so on. It uses SenseTalk. Not free, you could request a trial.
- [Routine Bot](http://www.routinebot.com/), I've never used it but it seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would also discourage using Image Recognition with SendKeys and Click at Coordinates or (Button Images) to do UI testing.  I have been recently using UI Automation to automate the testing of a WPF application with success.  By placing small breadcrumbs (Automation.AutomationID="OkButton") throughout our application's XAML I have been able to write some C# Unit Tests that exercise different aspects of the application.  Even without the breadcrumbs UI Automation is still capable of exercising an application, but it is slightly more difficult when trying to identify the controls on the UI.

A decent article on Code Project is available as a starting point.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UIAutomation.aspx

You will also need UI Spy, a free tool from Microsoft, which helps you find controls and manually exercise the controls through UI Automation as guidance for writing the scripts.  The tool is buried in the Windows Vista SDK, after installation search for UISpy.exe.  The UI Spy tool can still run on a Windows XP machine by just copying the EXE to the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider AutoItScript for driving Windows-based GUIs in test scenarios - AND scraping off the UIs. Consider tesseract open source optical character recognition. Also OpenCV for machine vision.

Free AutoItScript works at the API level in that you can read states of various Widgets and Windows sections, send actions to these UI components too, wait for state changes etc. It's possible to produce highly robust automation code that will ensure focusing on Windows and resolution independence.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggestion another solution.
It's not a complete UI automation framework, but rather a specific tool just for the Image validation.
It will allow you to ignore the unstable part of your images as well (random data, etc.)
It will integrate with any other UI testing framework you choose:Selenium, Sikuli, etc.

http://visualci.com

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comment! please Take a look at  RoutineBot – interface testing software based clicking on certain image patterns and see for yourself how this idea is implemented in an 
automation tool!

Comment: From RoutineBot's own FAQ: "If you use in your script image patters, and the original appearance of some, say button, in tested application changed, then script will not be executed correctly. So, when designing you scripts have in mind this possibility. There are some possible solutions to this problem: you can use ClickButton command, which uses button’s caption text (not its image). Another solution is using smaller image patters, in this case there are less chances for the pattern to be changed."
-- Like I said, image recognition ought to be considered as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but perhaps this answer may prove useful to someone.  I currently am using two products,

Testing Anywhere, by Automation Anywhere (http://www.automationanywhere.com/Testing/)

and Quick Test Professional, by HP (http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1172957#.UhJBwpLW5-k)

Both of them do the job well enough, and both support the use of image recognition. I am not entirely convinced that image recognition is in itself a bad thing. As with all things, you have to tailor your approach to your particular needs and use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add another entry to this thread. Things may have changed, not sure, but when I last saw the demo, this product offered Sikuli-like IDE/interface/capabilities while being a commercial product and supported actual devices beyond simulator. Don't know if the tool has improved to detect objects by identifiers beyond images now or not.

SeeTest from http://experitest.com